# Encountered error "Consider defining a bean of type 'java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference' in your configuration"

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting the below error while starting spring boot application.

> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference' in your configuration.

Below is the code .

```
package de.summer.sampleapplayerv1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"de.summer.sampleapplayerv1"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableJpaRepositories (basePackages ="de.summer.sampleapplayerv1.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Sampleapplayerv1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Sampleapplayerv1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package de.summer.sampleapplayerv1.service;

import de.summer.sampleapplayerv1.domain.QueueAndPublish;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class QueueAndPublishServiceImpl implements QueueAndPublishService{

    private final AtomicReference<List<QueueAndPublish>> currentJob;

    public QueueAndPublishServiceImpl(
            @Qualifier("currentJob") AtomicReference<List<QueueAndPublish>> currentJob
    ){
        this.currentJob=currentJob;
    }

    @Override
    public QueueAndPublish getJobStatus(UUID jobId) {
        return (QueueAndPublish) currentJob.get().stream()
                        .filter(j -> j.getJobId()==jobId)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public List<QueueAndPublish> getAllJobStatus() {
        return currentJob.get();
    }

    @Override
    public QueueAndPublish getCategoryDataProcess() {
        List<QueueAndPublish> processList=new ArrayList<QueueAndPublish>();
        QueueAndPublish process=QueueAndPublish.builder()
                                                .jobId(UUID.randomUUID())
                                                .jobName("Name for Job")
                                                .jobStatus("Not Yet Started")
                                                .build();
        Thread t1=new Thread(process.getJobId().toString()){
          @Override
          public void run(){
              log.info("How are you doing");
              process.setJobStatus("Completed");
          }
        };
        t1.start();
        processList.add(process);
        currentJob.set(processList);
        return process;
    }

    @Override
    public QueueAndPublish getCatgeoryDataProcessStatus() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
package de.summer.sampleapplayerv1.domain;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.UUID;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
public class QueueAndPublish implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private UUID jobId;
    private String jobName;
    private String jobStatus;
}
```

If I remove the constructor, spring boot application is starting up without any errors. If included , start up is failing with unsatisfied dependency errors.

Can someone please help on what is wrong with config?

Answer (score 0):

You expect Spring to create an instance of class `QueueAndPublishServiceImpl` for the implementation of `QueueAndPublishService`. This instance needs a constructor parameter of type   `AtomicReference<List<QueueAndPublish>>` injected.

But you obviously do not define any Spring bean (Bean, Component, Service, ...) of that type.

**Edit:**

```java
public QueueAndPublishServiceImpl(
            @Qualifier("currentJob") AtomicReference<List<QueueAndPublish>> currentJob
    ){
        this.currentJob=currentJob;
    }
```

Here you define a constructor parameter to have a `AtomicReference<List<QueueAndPublish>>`, and even specify it with a `@Qualifier`.  So you need to provide a Spring bean of this class with this qualifier, otherwise Spring cannot inject it into the constructor call.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you please elaborate your answer as I could not get it what you exactly meant here ?

Answer (score 0):

> Consider defining a bean of type 'java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference' in your configuration.

Means "something like" adding this to your `Sampleapplayerv1Application`:

```
@Bean("currentJob") AtomicReference<List<QueueAndPublish>> currentJob() {
   // or a list implementation of your choice.
   return new AtomicReference<>(new java.util.ArrayList<>()); 
}
```